# Administration menu links are incorrect

Tags: 8, navigation

I installed drupal 8 using composer, which installed at location /var/www/html/drupal8/web. I updated apache root directory to this location, which allows me to access the site at mysite.com (rather than mysite.com/drupal8/web). However, when I login to the admin console of drupal, none of the admin links work, such as content, structure, configuration, etc. All of these links are trying to use mysite.com/drupal8/web/.... which no longer works. Removing "drupal8/web" will allow me to access the associated sections of the site. Content on the site works correctly, but I'm unsure how to correct the administration links. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you access the site before moving your Apache root directory?  If so, it could just be a cache issue.  Try clearing your cache.

Comment: I did access before updating, however i did since clear cache, as well well as tried to access different browsers and even a different PC. The servers have also been restarted with no change to the behavior